# How to properly make a counting algorithm to count from file?

Tags: c, file, count

This is a program to find the largest even number and its times of occurring from an input file and output it to an output file. I'm having a problem with the output, there seems to be an extra iteration that messes things up.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n, num, i, even, count;

    FILE * fptr;
    FILE * fptro;

    fptr =fopen("maximpar.in", "r");
    fptro=fopen("maximpar.out", "w");

   /*scanning the first line from the file to get n for for()*/

    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n); 

    count = 0;
    even = INT_MIN;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &num);

    if( (num % 2 == 0 && num > even) || (even == num) ) 

    /*checking  for largest even number, 
    not sure about the ..||(even == num) part of the condition*/

    {
        even = num;
        count++;
    }

}

    fprintf(fptro, "%d %d", even, count);


    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fptro);

    return 0;
}
```

### Input file

```
 6
 9 6 9 8 9 8
```

### Output file

```
8 3
```

Why isn't the output file like this? I don't understand

```
8 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your count whenever you get a new larger number.

I didn't test this, but it should work:

```
cate = 0;
par = INT_MIN;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &b);

    // skip odd numbers
    if ((b % 2) != 0)
        continue;

    // get new larger number
    if (b > par) {
        par = b;
        cate = 1;
        continue;
    }

    // increment count on existing largest number
    if (b == par)
        ++cate;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I dont understand why skip iterations explicitly instead of only picking out the iterations that matter? Is there some sort of advantage?

Yes, it's better style. It allows simple single level indented `if` statements that can have their own comments.

It avoids a messy compound `if` or a triple level `if/else` ladder.

IMO, it's a common misconception [particularly among beginning C programmers] that a complex `if` will execute faster [or is somehow "better"] than several simple ones.

The first `if` could be thought of a "skip this iteration" test. Here, there's only one. But, for more complex code, there might be several.

The multiple condtion escapes *could* be handled in a single `if` with `if (c1 || c2 || c2 || ... || c10) continue;` but that gets messy fast.

Herein, for properly indented `if/else` ladder logic, we'd need:

```
if (cond1)
    do_stuff1;
else
    if (cond2)
        do_stuff2;
    else
        if (cond3)
            do_stuff3;
```

If we're not in a loop, here's a "trick" to avoid `if/else` ladder logic, by using `do { ... } while (0);`:

```
do {
    if (cond1) {
        do_stuff1;
        break;
    }

    if (cond2) {
        do_stuff2;
        break;
    }

    if (cond3) {
        do_stuff3;
        break;
    }
} while (0);
```

Comment: I dont understand why skip iterations explicitly instead of only picking out the iterations that matter? Is there some sort of advantage?

Comment: I see, our professors do insist on ''Coding Style'' in homeworks. This is helpful. but why did my output show 3? and which iteration did it have an extra count++;?

Comment: may i ask again why skip odds instead of directly getting them?

Answer (score 1):

enclose the condition

```
   if(  ( ...&&...) ||(....) )
```

Comment: While it may look neater like this, or possibly be crucial in some cases this didn't do anything for my problem

Comment: straight away ill start with 6 (6%2==0 && 6>-1) p=6,cnt=1 next 8  (8%2==0 && 8>6) p=8,cnt=2 next 8 again  ..||(8==8) cnt=3 unlike your case 6%2 && 6>-1 || 6==-1 cnt1,p=6 , 8%2 && 8>6 || 8==6 cnt=2,p=8 finally, 8%2 && 8>8 || 8==8 cnt will remain 2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because count was incremented from 0 to 1 when b = 6.  2 iterations later, b = 8 and now count = 2, and 2 iterations after that, b = 8 and count = 3.

I also recommend you nest your if statement in parentheses for readability.  Commenting would help too :)  I'm a stats guy, and I have no idea what you are doing based on your variables' names.

You need to reset your counter inside the if block if b > par.

Like:

if( num % 2 == 0 && num >= even) {

```
if (num > even){ 

    even = num; 
    count = 1; 

} else { 

    count++; 

}
```

}

Thanks.

JK

Comment: But theoretically my if() was executed only if it found a large number, perhaps everything after my || operator is messing something up?

Comment: You need to reset your counter inside the if block if b > par.

    if( num % 2 == 0 && num >= even)
    {
        if (num > even){
            even = b;
           count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
        
    }