# Are there range operators in the C programming language?

Tags: c, range, operators

Are there range operators in C like there are in, say, Swift (closed range, open range)?
For example, in a `switch` statement, in Swift I would write this:

```
switch num {
    case 144...168:
    print("Something between 144 and 168")

    case 120..<144:
    print("Something between 120 and 143")
    
    default: break
}
```

If I try something similar in C, using `printf` instead of `print` of course, I cannot use the same range operators. Is there something I can use instead?
Thank you

Comment: No, there isn't. Of course you can always write a series of `if`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a series of `if` statements.

When I do range matches, I create macros to simplify the code.

And, I've found that a `do { } while (0);` block can simplify things vs. a large `if/else` ladder.

Here is some code:

```
#define RNGE(_val,_lo,_hi) \
    (((_val) >= (_lo)) && ((_val) <= (_hi)))
#define RNGEM1(_val,_lo,_hi) \
    (((_val) >= (_lo)) && ((_val) < (_hi)))

do {
    if (RNGE(num,144,168)) {
        printf("Something between 144 and 168\n");
        break;
    }

    if (RNGEM1(num,120,144)) {
        printf("Something between 120 and 143\n")
        break;
    }

    // default ...
} while (0);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Nice! Not too familiar with macros, but they look like functions. What is the backslash at the end of the line? Also, why the underscores? Convention? Preference? Second and fourth line perfectly clear! –
> NotationMaster

Macros are a way to "generate" code. They are [usually] processed in a separate first stage of the compiler: the C preprocessor (aka `cpp`). They operate as if you "inserted" the code with an editor.

The backslashes are required *if* you want to define your macro on multiple lines [as I did].

We can look at the source generated by the macros with (e.g.)

```
cc -E -P -o foo.i foo.c
```

Here is the output of that stage:

```
do {
 if ((((num) >= (144)) && ((num) <= (168)))) {
  printf("Something between 144 and 168\n");
  break;
 }
 if ((((num) >= (120)) && ((num) < (144)))) {
  printf("Something between 120 and 143\n")
  break;
 }
} while (0);
```

The underscores are *my* personal convention (developed after 40+ years ;-).

Most people would define the macros as:

```
#define RNGE(num,lo,hi) \
    (((num) >= (lo)) && ((num) <= (hi)))
#define RNGEM1(num,lo,hi) \
    (((num) >= (lo)) && ((num) < (hi)))
```

I use them to distinguish the macro arguments from C symbols. Notice here I changed `_val` into `num`. I did that deliberately to use the same symbol your example used (i.e. `num`). Now, the generated output has `num` in it. But, is that `num` from the [function] scoped C variable *directly* (e.g. I forgot to define the argument in the macro) or did it come through the argument?

This are somewhat controversial because, in C, there are standards for libraries (e.g. POSIX) that reserve all symbols that start with "_" for standard library usage.

That is just a convention, however. It's rare for a symbol I define with "_" to conflict with any internal library symbol. If one ever does, I'm perfectly willing to accept the responsibility to change my code. In fact, in 40 years, I've *never* had such a conflict and have never had to rework code.

For macro arguments, they are in a different namespace, so far *less* likely to conflict with a global variable or function name in a [POSIX] library.

Also, I consider it to be extreme hubris on the part of POSIX to co-opt such a broad mechanism for themselves. In `python`, an "_" prefix is a convention that the object function is private to the object.

If you want the benefit of the "_" without the hassle of "violating" the convention (e.g):

```
#define RNGE(val_,lo_,hi_) \
    (((val_) >= (lo_)) && ((val_) <= (hi_)))
#define RNGEM1(val_,lo_,hi_) \
    (((val_) >= (lo_)) && ((val_) < (hi_)))
```

Macros are useful in certain situations where a function won't work. Consider the following where we replace the macro with an `inline` function:

```
static inline int
RNGE(int val,int lo,int hi)
{
    return (val >= lo) && (val <= hi);
}

// this works ...
int num;
do {
    if (RNGE(num,144,168)) {
        printf("Something between 144 and 168\n");
        break;
    }

    // default ...
} while (0)

// this blows up at compile time ...
int arr[1000];
int *ptr = &arr[37];
do {
    if (RNGE(ptr,&arr[144],&arr[168])) {
        printf("Something between array elements 144 and 168\n");
        break;
    }

    // default ...
} while (0)
```

C doesn't have overloaded functions like some languages (e.g. C++). So, we have to explicitly generate separate functions for each argument type.

In this instance, the macro works for *any* type that can be compared.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

For more on using `do { ... } while (0)` in place of `if/else` ladder logic or `switch/case` see my answer: [How to properly make a counting algorithm to count from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917175/how-to-properly-make-a-counting-algorithm-to-count-from-file/53917340#53917340)

> thank you for the extra explanation. I recall in Swift these range operators would be perfect for usage in a switch statement. Yet, here, if I use this macro in the switch, the compiler still tells "Expression is not an integer constant expression". Am I missing something here? –
> NotationMaster

The short answer is ...

1. with `switch (switch_expression)` then `switch_expression` can be just about anything.
2. But, a limitation of C with `case case_expression` is that `case_expression` can *only* be something that evaluates to a *constant* at *compile* time.
3. `switch/case` is a [very useful] nicety. But, anything it does can be done with `if/else`.
4. So, the way to handle this is to use the code in my first example above.

*Warning:* This is where you should probably stop reading ... :-)

The long answer ...

So, *why* does C have this restriction? Mostly historical. But, C wants to generate extremely fast code.

Many `switch/case` blocks use *consecutive* numbers in the `case` expressions:

```
switch (num) {
case 1:
    x = 23;
    break;

case 2:
    y = 37;
    break;

case 3:
    z = 19;
    break;

case ...:
    ...;
    break;

case 100:
    q = 28;
    break;

default:
    abort();
    break;
}
```

The simple/obvious code would be (using `if/else` ladder logic that I convert here to use my `do/while/0` "trick" would be:

```
do {
    if (num == 1) {
        x = 23;
        break;
    }

    if (num ==  2) {
        y = 37;
        break;
    }

    if (num == 3) {
        z = 19;
        break;
    }

    // cases for 4-99 ...

    if (num == 100) {
        q = 28;
        break;
    }

    // default:
    abort();
} while (0);
```

However ... There's a *lot* of `if` statements in this. But, because the `case` expressions are *consecutive*, the optimizing compiler can detect this and generate [asm] code that does a range check (i.e. *if* `num` is within the range `1-100`) and can use the `num` value to index into a pointer table that jumps directly to the corresponding code snippet.

Here is some pseudo code that shows this:

```
static void *switch_vector[] = {
    &&L_1,
    &&L_2,
    &&L_3,
    ...,
    &&L_100
};

if (RNGE(num,1,100))
    goto switch_vector[num - 1];
else
    goto L_DEFAULT;

L_1:
    x = 23;
    goto L_ENDSWITCH;

L_2:
    y = 37;
    goto L_ENDSWITCH;

L_3:
    z = 19;
    goto L_ENDSWITCH;

// more labels ...

L_100:
    q = 28;
    goto L_ENDSWITCH;

L_DEFAULT:
    abort();

L_ENDSWITCH:
    // code after switch
```

*Side note:* I called this "pseudo" code, but this is actually *valid* C code using the very advanced usage of a "computed" `goto` in C. Don't actually use it as it's virtually never needed. The compiler will usually generate much better code using the simpler constructs above. Remember, I *did* warn you :-)

See:

1. [Can you make a computed goto in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380073/can-you-make-a-computed-goto-in-c)
2. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/07/12/computed-goto-for-efficient-dispatch-tables

Comment: Nice! Not too familiar with macros, but they look like functions. What is the backslash at the end of the line? Also, why the underscores? Convention? Preference? Second and fourth line perfectly clear!

Comment: better would be inline function

Comment: @pm100 how would that work in this case?

Comment: `inline int range(int v, int h,int l){return (v < hi && v > l);}`

Comment: @Craig Estey : thank you for the extra explanation. I recall in Swift these range operators would be perfect for usage in a switch statement. Yet, here, if I use this macro in the switch, the compiler still tells "Expression is not an integer constant expression". Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Standard C (as of 2022...) does not provide such range operators.

But GCC provides [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) as an extension:

> **6.30 Case Ranges**
>
> You can specify a range of consecutive values in a single case label,
> like this:
>
> ```
> case low ... high:
> ```
>
> This has the same effect as the proper number of individual case
> labels, one for each integer value from low to high, inclusive.
>
> This feature is especially useful for ranges of ASCII character codes:
>
> ```
> case 'A' ... 'Z':
> ```
>
> Be careful: Write spaces around the ..., for otherwise it may be
> parsed wrong when you use it with integer values. For example, write
> this:
>
> ```
> case 1 ... 5:
> ```
>
> rather than this:
>
> ```
> case 1...5:
> ```

Note the warning about spaces and integer values.

Also, this

```
case 120..<144:
```

in your hypothetical code would be written as

```
case 120 ... 143:
```

using the GCC extension.

Comment: Forgive the ignorance, I'm learning: what is GCC?

Comment: @NotationMaster  GCC is [the GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/).  It's a free, open-source collection of compilers that's effectively the *de facto* "standard" compiler used on the non-Windows systems you'll encounter outside of embedded programming.

Comment: Is it available as an in-browser compiler or as a separate software on macOS? Reading on the website it seems to be a command-line utility through homebrew or MacPort?

Comment: @NotationMaster I'm not really familiar with Macs, but there's an entire Stackexchange site dedicated to Macs/Apple products:  https://apple.stackexchange.com  There's even a question that seems appropriate:  [**Installed gcc with Homebrew, now how to use that gcc instead of clang?**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245891/installed-gcc-with-homebrew-now-how-to-use-that-gcc-instead-of-clang)  Offhand, if you are using `clang` already, it might support the GCC range extension and you wouldn't have to change.

Comment: Problem is, I am not using the Terminal right now for this, I would prefer some kind of GUI if possible. Or does anyone know whether Xcode can make use of GCC? If so, how?

Comment: Just tried the `case 120 ... 143` in Xcode, and it works. The caveat was to have spaces around the numbers, which is different from how Swift allows to do, where both are accepted.